# CSS doesn't let children make parent bigger

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Take a look at this site I'm working on: http://appload.nu/flygklubb
The first menu-item has children. But, as you can see, the children make the parent bigger. How can I prevent the parent from getting bigger and at the same time make all of the children the same size?

Comment: I don't see the problem on Chrome or IE9.

Comment: You need to be more specific. I don't know what you mean by the children getting bigger because, visually, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PriorityMark and @Rob, change one of the submenu items to be a long block of text (e.g. `laksjdf lkjas dlkfj alskjd lakjsd`) to see the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this image
http://piclair.com/data/t4xi8.jpg
The gap between "flygplan" and "flygfältet" is much bigger than the gap between "flygfältet" and "flygklubben" and that is because the text in the drop-down menu causes the menu-item to grow. Now i want to prevent that... how?

Comment: @anton-gildebrand, Do you want the children the same width as *eachother*, or the same width as the *parent*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the child UL's absolute.

Change your CSS for:

```
#topnavigation > ul > li ul { visibility: hidden; }
```

To

```
#topnavigation > ul > li ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Due to his `height` restrictions on the submenu `li` and `li a`, this breaks readability.

Comment: @AntonGildebrand, keep in mind that if the amount of text in the submenu is changed, the font size or family is changed, or the padding is changed, this will break the usability (submenus will overlap eachother). See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## Same width as parent

To keep the submenu the same width as the menu, but avoid stretching the menu:

```
#topnavigation ul li {
 position:relative;
}
#topnavigation ul li ul {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
}
#topnavigation ul li ul li {
 height:auto;
 min-height:15px;
}
#topnavigation ul li ul li a {
 height:auto;
 min-height:15px;
}
```

## *-OR-* Same width as eachother

```
#topnavigation ul li ul {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
}
```

***Note:** I also recommend adding a background color (or less busy image) to the submenu items for better readability.*

Answer (score -1):

The Elment gots bigger because of the padding on the

```
#topnavigation a {
  padding: 10px 11px;
}
```

1. change the padding - its fot padding top and bottom. (i would prepare 4px)
2. remove the height from the #topnavigation a - it is not necessary
3. remove the height from the #topnavigation li - it is also not necessary
4. change the height of the div (#topnavigation). (i would prepare 26px)

Your new CSS:

```
#topnavigation li {
display: list-item;
}

#topnavigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 11px;
}

#topnavigation {
    background-color: #ADA287;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 970px;
}
```

Comment: `1.` is not the reason it got bigger. It's due to the width of the text in the submenu (and the submenu forcing the menu item to expand to it. `2.` and `.3` are valid points. `4.` is only needed if `1.` is followed exactly (changing 10px to 5px). In short, this solution does not work (except out of luck).